# Laravel 5.4 - Track can't pass mime validation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm confusing because some .mp3 files can't pass my validation:

```
 mimes:mpga
```

var_dump of this files looks the same with files that successfuly passed validation, they all have the same mimeType `-mimeType: "audio/mp3"`
I've tryed to extend validation rule but that's doesn't work: `mimes:mpga,audio/mpeg,audio/mp3`

Here is the track that can't pass http://dropmefiles.com/L1iGQ

**UPD**
`$file->getErrorMessage()` returns `The file "Emmanuelle - Italove.mp3" was not uploaded due to an unknown error.`
And that makes me cry because in real life there is no problems with saving this track if not using validation

Comment: I just checked mime for that file on ubuntu, `file --mime-type -b "Emmanuelle - Italove.mp3"` returns **application/octet-stream**. Maybe that helps

Comment: `$file->getMimeType()` returns **application/octet-stream** too but `mimes:application/octet-stream` doesn't works

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you should not rely for MIME type if you want to validate uploaded file. My arguments are:

- MIME type is used in web primarily to tell browser what content it should expect, so the browser could render/process it properly. It sorts of serve the function of file extension in the web. But the problem is, ***a particular file type doesn't have one-to-one relationship with their MIME type***. So if you try to only allow a particular file extension based on their MIME type, you might get unexpected result. you could check here: [list of file extension vs mime](https://www.sitepoint.com/mime-types-complete-list/)
- On top of that, if you do try to upload a file from a browser, and let browser decide what MIME type it should attach, you may also get different result, depending on the browser that sends it (e.g. Firefox would give mp3-> audio/mpeg; while Chrome would give mp3-> audio/mp3) type check.

So my advice is to just use validation based on the given extension, if your intention is to only allowing mp3 file to be uploaded.